laravel api to update data is not working
I am sending data from ionic project using api. And receiving from laravel. My "Add" product api is working fine. But "Update" product api is not working.
I can see from browser inspection tool that Request payload got data which is being send to laravel. So, data is being send but laravel is not able to real that data.
This is update function for api.
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{

// Validate request
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'account_type' => 'required|in:1,2',
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'description' => 'nullable|string',
    'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0'
]);

// Update product
$product->update($validatedData);

return response()->json($product);
}

This is giving following error
account_type    [ "The account type field is required." ]
name    [ "The name field is required." ]
price   [ "The price field is required." ]
and so on..

Laravel unable to read data for some reason.

Update

<form [formGroup]="productForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<!-- Add Type -->
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Add Type <span class="required">*</span></ion-label>
  <ion-radio-group formControlName="account_type">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Individual</ion-label>
      <ion-radio slot="start" value="1"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Business</ion-label>
      <ion-radio slot="start" value="2"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-radio-group>
</ion-item>

<!-- Ad Title -->
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="floating">Ad Title <span class="required">*</span></ion-label>
  <ion-input formControlName="name" type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<!-- Submit Buttons -->
<div class="ion-padding">
  <ion-button type="submit" expand="block" [disabled]="productForm.invalid">
    {{ isEditMode ? 'Update Product' : 'Submit Now!' }}
  </ion-button>
  <ion-button expand="block" color="light">Preview</ion-button>
</div>

Didn't add all field of form here to make it short.
TS FILE
onSubmit() {
if (this.productForm.valid) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const formValues = this.productForm.value;

  // Append all form data
  Object.keys(formValues).forEach((key) => {
    if (key !== 'image' && key !== 'additionalImages') {
      formData.append(key, formValues[key]);
    }
  });

  // Handle file inputs
  const mainImage = document.querySelector('[formControlName="image"]') as HTMLInputElement;
  if (mainImage && mainImage.files && mainImage.files[0]) {
    formData.append('image', mainImage.files[0]);
  }

  const additionalImages = document.querySelector('[formControlName="additionalImages"]') as HTMLInputElement;
  if (additionalImages && additionalImages.files) {
    Array.from(additionalImages.files).forEach((file) => {
      formData.append('additionalImages[]', file);
    });
  }

  // Differentiate between add and update
  if (this.isEditMode) {
    const productId = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('productId'));
    this.productService.updateProductPost(productId, formData).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log('Product updated successfully:', response);
        this.router.navigate(['/success']);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error updating product:', error);
      }
    );
  } else {
      // Get the query string parameter
    const categoryId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('categoryId'); // Extract categoryId from query string
    console.log('Category ID:', categoryId);

    // Get the sessionStorage value
    const userId = sessionStorage.getItem('userId'); // Extract userId from sessionStorage

    // Append query string and sessionStorage data to the formData
    if (categoryId) {
      formData.append('category_id', Number(categoryId).toString());
    }
    if (userId) {
      formData.append('seller_id', Number(userId).toString());
    }

    this.productService.addProduct(formData).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log('Product added successfully:', response);
        this.router.navigate(['/success']);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error adding product:', error);
      }
    );
  }
} else {
  console.error('Form is invalid');
}
}

PRODUCT.SERVICE.TS
//Add product (is working)
addProduct(product: FormData): Observable<Product> {
  return this.http.post<Product>(`${this.apiUrl}/products`, product);
}

//update producd
updateProductPost(productId: number, product: FormData): Observable<Product> {
  return this.http.put<Product>(`${this.apiUrl}/products-update/${productId}`, product);
}

Laravel route in api.php
Route::put('products-update/{id}', [ProductApi::class, 'update']);


Your shared code is not sufficient to tell what exactly has gone wrong in your code.This issue may rise due to incorrect model-binding,mass-assignment issue in model. Even if the value of account_type is passed as string validation will fail.To ensure what exactly gone wrong do this dd($product) to check what the $product instance returns.Also share you route for this update function so that we can help you out.

show us your form. and check  'Content-Type': 'application/json',

Even if you see data being sent in the browser inspection, it might not be in the right format or the content-type is not the correct one for the data format being sent. In your case it is 100% an issue with the code sending the data and not a laravel issue. Please add the ionic code you used to make the api request to your question.

I have updated the code

if you remove the code // Handle file inputs does it work ?*

@N69S I commented the image file code but still same error.

@Rishabh,Hi did you try dd($product) inside update(..) to check if it shows expected data ?

@Subha Only field name I can see in dd(), not their value.

This is the case of incorrectly defined implicit model-binding.
When you use implicit model-binding you need to use the same name for the Route parameter and for the injected model instance into the controller method(in your case update(Request $request, Product $product)).
So change you route defination like this.
Route::put('products-update/{product}', [ProductApi::class, 'update']);

N:B :-

In laravel part this is the issue that causes the error for sure. But in the frontend part I am not able to suggest you anything even if there is any issue since I am not familiar with the angular at all.
Make the above changes and recheck.
Also go through the above link that I have provided where you will get the more details about the implicit model-binding.


the binding was successful, otherwise when calling the update method, it would trigger an error as $product can't be null.

This solve the issue but it only worked when I use api call suggested by @N69S in service.ts file. So my issue solved by 50% your answer and 50% n68s

@Rishabh , Thanks for your confirmation.

The http method PUT doesnt "necessarily  carry a body" by RFC standards.
Library like axios or even servers like apache can completely ignore processing the body in a put request.
there are 2 workarounds:
1- Use POST for updates too:
As you can see, the 2 url structure are different from insert and update since one needs an id, so you can use post to update too
Route::post('product', [ProductApi::class, 'store']);
Route::post('product/{id}', [ProductApi::class, 'update']);

2- Use POST with the input _method:
In laravel you can send a POST request and have it treated like a PUT one if it has the input _method=PUT.
PRODUCT.SERVICE.TS
//update producd
updateProductPost(productId: number, product: FormData): Observable<Product> {
  product.append('_method','PUT');
  return this.http.post<Product>(`${this.apiUrl}/products-update/${productId}`, product);
}

Notice that this.http.post is used and not this.http.put
Any of the two solutions would work for your case.

Hi, I tried both solutions. In both cases, there wasn't any error. Response was blank (no error, no warning) and it didn't update the data in db.

I used your 2nd solution and combined with Subha's given solution, then it worked, Thanks :)

Having understood the problem, let's diagnose the possible causes.
The first step is to know if the request data is arriving correctly at the server. And to know that, let's debug what's coming. We will use the dd($request->all()) function to get all the request data, make sure to place it above $request->validate().
Having the result of dd(), check if the data is correct. If the data is not correct, the problem is certainly in the frontend request.
But if the data is correct, the problem could certainly be in the validations done in $request->validate([...]).
I hope I helped!
